An intruder completed the WordPress installation through the web interface. How to delete & reset to default
Problem
I'm using this tutorial to set up WordPress with Docker:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose
While doing steps, someone else completed the step 6 of the tutorial by completing the installation through the web interface.
Apparently, the intruder has created admin username & password and other things.
I mean, the intruder has completed this wizard and has set admin username & password:

Question
How can I delete everything the intruder has created and reset to default to be able to complete the installation myself through the web interface?

Solution
I removed the containers along with volumes:
docker compose stop
docker compose down -v


-v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the volumes
section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
attached to containers.

Then I had to do some certbot steps of the tutorial again :(
Fortunately, I was able to set up the dashboard with my own admin username & password:

